# how to make static variable initialized

Tags: iphone, objective-c, static

I want to save the "dataFilePath" as a static variable so that it can be initialized when first time use "Constants" and no need to instantiate the Class , for example [Constants SDataFilePath]. But the trues is that the init method is not called. How can I do to meet my request?  (In Java the construct method will be called the fist time to access the Class).

```
@implementation Constants

static NSString *dataFilePath;

-(id)init
{ 
    NSLog(@"init!");
    if(self = [super init]) {
        dataFilePath = [self getDataFilePathWithArg:dbfile];
    }    
    return self; 
}  

+(NSString *)SDataFilePath {
    return dataFilePath; 
}
....
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could make Constants a singleton. Leave your code how it is and add this method to the .m:

```
+ (Constants *)sharedConstants 
{
    static Constants *_sharedConstants = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
        _sharedConstants = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return _sharedConstants;
}
```

And the method declaration to the .h:

```
+ (Constants *)sharedConstants;
```

Then access your variable like this:

```
[[Constants sharedConstants] SDataFilePath]
```

That will force an init the first time you access [Constants sharedConstants] (and only the first time). Also, you'll need to change +(NSString *)SDataFilePath to an instance method, not class method:

```
-(NSString *)SDataFilePath
```

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done this way. Any reason why you want this path to be static? You might want to look into setting dataFilePath with a getter, but no setter and instantiating the class as a singleton. That way you can set the path by some internal method and share the instance as a singleton. See [here](http://iphone.galloway.me.uk/iphone-sdktutorials/singleton-classes/)